# Velocity Profile of the Upper Atmosphere

Tags: velocity, earth, atmospheric-science

Consider an Earth-Centered Inertial (ECI) frame in which the tangential (to Earth's surface) velocity is measured. Now consider obtaining constant average velocity profiles of the atmosphere as a function of altitude from perhaps 100 km to 1000 km about the equator of the earth (viz. no cross-wind due to a nonzero inclination). Is this profile more likely to look like a solid-body rotator or a Lamb-Oseen Vortex? I would suppose the latter due to the large mean free path in the free molecular flow regions at high altitude but much of the information I find online implies the former! I am not an atmospheric scientist and thus know of no trustworthy source for this information. In case anyone is interested, knowing the velocity profile allows a better calculation of the drag force on satellites in LEO, thus a better estimate of LEO lifetimes.

Comment: I initially thought I could find something on this in a few seconds, but it turned out to be very difficult to find anything.  There are models at:  [WAWG](http://www2.cesm.ucar.edu/working-groups/wawg) and [HAO](http://www.hao.ucar.edu/modeling/tgcm/) but I did not find any nice cartoon-like images similar to what they have for the temperature profile of the atmosphere.  Perhaps more searching would result in a solution but that will have to wait...